# Bootstrap v5 Grid is not working in "col-lg" case

Tags: bootstrap-5, bootstrap-grid

I am learning bootstrap, and I am seeing a course focused on Bootstrap 4. I am not sure if the following has to do with that, but I am not able to go through this exercise.

I am making this grid for a large screen size:

[image: Example at largest screen]

And when reducing the screen size to medium, the grid should now look like:

[image: Example at medium screen]

Finally, the screen should look like this in shorter screen size than medium:

[image]

I have tried the following code but I am not successful in the largest size:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        div[class^="col"] {
            height: 100px;
            background: #fdca6d;
            border: 1px solid white;
        }
    </style>
    <title>Grid challenge 2</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container mt-4">
        <!--Start first row-->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
                Row 1 / Col 1
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
                Row 1 / Col 2
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
                Row 1 / Col 3
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
                Row 1 / Col 4
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--End first row-->
        <!--Start second row-->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg">
                Row 2 / Col 1
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg">
                Row 2 / Col 2
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg">
                Row 2 / Col 3
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg">
                Row 2 / Col 4
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg">
                Row 2 / Col 5
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg">
                Row 2 / Col 6
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg">
                Row 2 / Col 7
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg">
                Row 2 / Col 8
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg">
                Row 2 / Col 9
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg">
                Row 2 / Col 10
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--End second row-->
    </div>

    <!--Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is how it looks like for me:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In your codeply code it works perfectly, but it does not work for me through codepen https://codepen.io/BlancaMorillo/pen/NWjxQQE . Does this might have something to do with the lines where I call bootstrap? Because they are the same in terms of the container content.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Bootstrap 5.1 (update Aug 2021)**

Bootstrap 5.1 has been released and the bug with auto-layout and sized columns has been fixed. Therefore, combining auto-layout columns with sized grid columns should now work as expected.

Here you can see [mix and match columns working as expected](https://www.codeply.com/p/K2I2hCHTB5)

---

**Bootstrap 5.0.2**

This [is a bug](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/34335) that was introduced in Bootstrap 5.0.2. This is because the generated CSS order of the auto-layout columns *col-{bp}* were reversed with order of the sized columns *col-{bp}-{width}*. In your case this is making the  `col-md-6` override the `col-lg`.

[Not working in 5.0.2](https://codeply.com/p/vSBvLXraBS)

[Working in 5.0.1](https://codeply.com/p/ce7BQsCxPx)

As you can see in the Github thread https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/34335 there's a proposed fix for the next 5.1.x release.

Answer (score 1):

If you want 10 columns on large displays and above, you could use [`row-cols`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/#row-columns) and define a custom style for 10 columns, something like this:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<style>
    div[class^="col"] {
        height: 100px;
        background: #fdca6d;
        border: 1px solid white;
    }

    @media (min-width:992px) {
        .row-cols-lg-10 > * {
            flex: 0 0 auto;
            width: 10%;
        }
    }
</style>

<div class="container mt-4">
    <!--Start first row-->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
            Row 1 / Col 1
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
            Row 1 / Col 2
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
            Row 1 / Col 3
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
            Row 1 / Col 4
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--End first row-->
    <!--Start second row-->
    <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2 row-cols-lg-10">
        <div class="col">
            Row 2 / Col 1
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            Row 2 / Col 2
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            Row 2 / Col 3
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            Row 2 / Col 4
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            Row 2 / Col 5
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            Row 2 / Col 6
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            Row 2 / Col 7
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            Row 2 / Col 8
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            Row 2 / Col 9
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            Row 2 / Col 10
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--End second row-->
</div>
```