# Bootstrap 5 columns with equal-width only from breakpoint "md"

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid, breakpoints, bootstrap-5, col

I have used this code several times in Bootstrap 4 (on mobile columns have full width - from "md" the columns have equal-width):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md">
      1 of 2
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md">
      2 of 2
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md">
      3 of 3
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md">
      4 of 4
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md">
      5 of 5
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I use this code in Bootstrap 5 "col-12" overwrites "col-md".

**How can I have on mobile the columns with full width and starting from "md" equal width, using Bootstrap 5?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I recently [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68263698/bootstrap-v5-grid-is-not-working-in-col-lg-case/68274066#68274066), this is a [bug that was introduced in 5.0.2](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/34335).

Until it's fixed, a workaround in your case would be to use `row-cols-*` instead...

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-5">
    <div class="col">
      1 of 2
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      2 of 2
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      3 of 3
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      4 of 4
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      5 of 5
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codeply.com/p/BusA6Eyw8K