# How can I use bootstrap 5 grid mix and match as bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4, sass, bootstrap-5

I've been using bootstrap 4 on my angular 12 project for a while, and today I've upgraded to bootstrap 5.
I know some properties have changed, but I've read that the grid system is identical.

I regularly use "Mix and Match" columns as written in the documentation, for example

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm"></div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-auto"></div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This example it's working very well with Bootstrap v4.* but not on v5.

It is supposed to have only 1 row where the first and third columns try to get all the available space and the second column fits your content.

What I saw on the Chrome DevTools that the col-12 class takes precedence over the col-sm class, even on larger screens.

[image: Bootstrap Grid]

Any ideas to try to solve this problem?

Comment: This should be possible with bs5, I just don't get your exact requirement: So first and third col are always equal width (e,g like col-2) and middle column takes all of the rest space?

Comment: @cloned The middle column fits on your own content, and the first and third works as you said.
This is what i want -> e,g.( 1ºCol = 45% 2ºCol = 10% 3ºCol = 45%) on "sm" breakpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I recently [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68263698/bootstrap-v5-grid-is-not-working-in-col-lg-case/68274066#68274066), this is a [bug that was introduced in 5.0.2](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/34335) because the order of the column declarations was changed, making col-12 override col-sm on all breakpoints.

Until it's fixed, a workaround in your case would be to simply remove the `col-12` (it's not needed since col-12 is the default)...

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">col</div>
    <div class="col-sm-auto">col</div>
    <div class="col-sm">col</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codeply.com/p/gUgPktyAyA

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't find the post you mentioned.
I can remove col-12 from my entire project and just use breakpoints (eg col-sm col-md-6 col-lg-12) because col-12 is the default or do you think they will solve this and will go back to the previous solution?

Comment: Bootstrap 5.1 has been released: here's your old code working: https://codeply.com/p/n9aqzTWoGq

Comment: Fortunately, I rolled back to Bootstrap 4 expecting this fix. 
Good news, now I can update again ;)